# How can I change color in RIVE?

Tags: javascript, rive

I'm looking to dynamically change the color of an object in my Rive file directly through my JavaScript code. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I have understood it is possible with flutter, but i don´t get how its done on javascript.

```js
const r = new rive.Rive({
  src: "email6.riv",
  canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
  autoplay: true,
  artboard: "New Artboard",
  stateMachines: "email_hover",

  onLoad: () => {
    r.resizeDrawingSurfaceToCanvas();
  },
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" / -->
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@rive-app/canvas@2.9.1"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please revise the demo I created above to show the problem. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I think you can use the state-machine bool